# How to implement Pattern Layout in log4j2 2.17.1 migrated from log4j 1.2.17 version?

Tags: java

Migrated from log4j 1.2.17 to log4j2 2.17.1 and getting issue in Pattern Layout class.

```
    PatternLayout pl = PatternLayout();
            pl.setConversionPattern("%m  :%d%n");
            // setFile(new File(theQFileName));
            FileAppender appender;
            try {
                appender = new FileAppender(pl, theQFileName, false);
                lLogger.addAppender(appender);
            }
```

Above snippet was used in log4j 1.2.17 version and after migration getting compilation error for Pattern Layout and File Appender class.

```
[ERROR]         PatternLayout pl = new PatternLayout();
[ERROR]                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The constructor PatternLayout() is undefined

[ERROR]         pl.setConversionPattern("%m  :%d%n");
[ERROR]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method setConversionPattern(String) is undefined for the type PatternLayout

[ERROR]         appender = new FileAppender(pl, theQFileName, false);
[ERROR]                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The constructor FileAppender(PatternLayout, String, boolean) is undefined
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: Above code was used in  log4j 1.2.17 version and after migrating to log4j2 2.17.1 I am getting compilation error for Pattern Layout and File Appender class

Comment: Log4j version 2.x is a major new version. This means that you shouldn't expect upgrading to work by just changing the version number from 1.2.17 to 2.17.1. You'll need to modify your code as well. See the [Migrating from Log4j 1.x to 2.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) guide on the Log4J website.